# How to find the maximum of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n\left(a_i\sum\limits_{j=1}^i\frac{b_j}{a_j}\right)$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_{i}>0$ and $b_{i}\ge 0$ for $1\le i\le n$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}=n,\tag{1}$$
and
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}+\prod_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}=\dfrac{1}{2}.\tag{2}$$
Find the maximum of
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(a_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{i}\dfrac{b_{j}}{a_{j}}\right).$$
I guess this maximum is at most $1$.

Comment: What is the question? What is $(x)_{\mathrm{max}}$?

Comment: Your last expression is broken. You have used $i$ as the indices for both summation and product.

Comment: Please answer the two questions in my previous comment.

Comment: $\max{(a_{i},b_{i}\in R^n)}$

Comment: Finally decided to rewrite this question, simply to make it understandable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no maximum value for $n\geq 2$.

Let $a_1$ be much smaller than the other terms. The constraints do not prevent $a_1$ from being arbitrarily close to $0$. and in the final product $a_1$ occurs once and $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{b_i}{a_i} \approx \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n b_i}{a_1}$ occurs $n$ times. The other terms do not change much, and the function to be maximised tends towards growing like $a^{1-n}$.

Comment: oh,Sorry,I have edit this problem,Thank you

Comment: math110: The asymptotics $a_1\to0$ considered in this answer still shows there is no maximum, no?